# Install multiple PostgreSQL versions with different PostGIS plugin versions on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, postgresql

I have a server with Ubuntu 12.04.5 (precise) which runs two different PostgreSQL versions (8.3 & 9.1) on two different ports (5432 & 5433). I've installed them from the default package sources. Everything runs nice and clean.

The 8.3 Setup uses the PostGIS Plugin (Version 1.5.3-2). For the 9.1 setup I would like to install PostGIS in a Version > 2.0. I fear, that I'll break the (important) running 8.3 setup when I manually install a new PostGIS version. The [prefix parameter of the ./configure-script seems to be broken](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#installation_configuration) and I don't know how to prevent the new version from overwriting the old one.

Is there a safe way to enable the new extension version in the 9.1 setup?

Please let me know, if you need further information about the system to answer this.

Comment: The option `--with-pgconfig=FILE` to the `./configure` script might help, where FILE should be the pg_config of the postgres installation (usually `/usr/lib/9.1/bin/pg_config` for 9.1). After running `./configure` you should carefully inspect the output and the Makefile(s) to see where the installation would go.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately there's neither a pg_config file in `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/` nor in `/usr/lib/postgresql/8.3/bin/`.

Comment: Seems to be a pretty ugly [problem](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/MODULES-1213?focusedCommentId=102562&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-102562)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 running with postgreSQL server 9.1, 9.3 and 9.5, where 9.5 has postgis 2.2 installed (via package postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2). In normal server installation, there is `/usr/bin/pg_config`, a script which first looks for `pg_config` in `/usr/lib/postgresql/*/bin/` (and, if existing, uses the latest version), and if there is none uses `/usr/bin/pg_config.libpq-dev`which is part of the client developer installation. You can just try running `pg_config`to see if it finds a version, and where it points to.

I downloaded `postgis-2.2.4.tar.gz`, unpacked and tried to run ./configure. This ended up with an error message, saying I had to install the server developer package. So I did `sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.5` (for 9.5; you should install 9.1, see http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/postgresql-server-dev-9.1). This did provide `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_config`, and `./configure` did succeed.

`grep PGSQL config.log` gave

```
| #define PGSQL_LOCALEDIR "/usr/share/locale"
| #define POSTGIS_PGSQL_VERSION 95
| #define PGSQL_LOCALEDIR "/usr/share/locale"
| #define POSTGIS_PGSQL_VERSION 95
| #define PGSQL_LOCALEDIR "/usr/share/locale"
| #define POSTGIS_PGSQL_VERSION 95
| #define PGSQL_LOCALEDIR "/usr/share/locale"
| #define POSTGIS_PGSQL_VERSION 95
PGSQL_BE_CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/include/postgresql/9.5/server'
PGSQL_BINDIR='/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin'
PGSQL_DOCDIR='/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-9.5'
PGSQL_FE_CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/include/postgresql'
PGSQL_FE_LDFLAGS='-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpq'
PGSQL_MANDIR='/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/man'
PGSQL_SHAREDIR='/usr/share/postgresql/9.5'
POSTGIS_PGSQL_VERSION='95'
#define PGSQL_LOCALEDIR "/usr/share/locale"
#define POSTGIS_PGSQL_VERSION 95
```

so the installation paths (BINDIR, DOCDIR, MANDIR and SHAREDIR) all point to the latest (9.5) installation. After successful `make` then `make -n install` (be sure to not forget the `-n`!) showed the installation paths. Most of them pointed to `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib` and `/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/extension`, with the exception of `liblwgeom`, which would be installed in `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`.

So, you first could try `./configure` (which won't harm) and see if it gives an error, and if not, where the installation would go to. Probably you have to install the development files, which will also install the correct `pg_config` for your version. As long as you do not `sudo make install`, nothing should be installed.

**And, of course, have a trusted current backup of your running installation!**

Comment: I will accept this answer because it seems to cover the complete process. Nevertheless I realised, that even with this setup I'll be only able to install PostGIS 2.2. Together with some other problems that are linked to the database and its users it's more convenient to set up an other physical machine with the latest versions of PostgreSQL and PostGIS. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. If possible it is always the best solution to have different machines (maybe virtual ones) for such complex installations.